# SQL UPDATE and CASE statement does not work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, case, common-table-expression

I have the following table "Sales" in MS SQL Server, where [FieldX] is not updated properly:

[image]

(..[My comment] is of course not an actual column in the table)

The reason why the last 3 rows should be = 3, is because I am updating the fields with the following rules:

```
with cte_previous_rows AS (
SELECT Staff_Id, LAG(FieldX) OVER (partition by Staff_Id ORDER by [date]) as Prev_Row
FROM Sales )

UPDATE Sales
SET FieldX = (CASE WHEN Staff_id_sales < 1500 AND ClosedSale = 0 THEN 0
           WHEN Staff_id_sales = 1500 and CosedSale = 0 THEN 5
           WHEN Staff_id_sales > 3000 and c.Prev_Row <> 2 and c.Prev_Row = 1 OR c.Prev_Row = 0 THEN 2
           WHEN Staff_id_sales > 3000 and c.Prev_Row = 2 or c.Prev_Row = 3 THEN 3 END) 
FROM Sales as Sales
JOIN cte_previous_rows as c
 on sales.staff_id = c.staff_id
```

The idea here is to identify what the previous row holds as value in [FieldX]. By "previous row" I refer to other rows with the SAME staff_id, and the closest previous [date]

The last two WHEN statements do not work as intended, as I get the output displayed in Sales table.

The correct output should look like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can it be fixed? Thank you.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements. I note in your second `WHEN` you have `AND CosedSale = 0`, however, that `WHEN` will never be able to evaluate to true as the prior `WHEN` has `OR ClosedSale = 0`; thus if that was true `0` will be returned and the next `WHEN` won't be evaluated. Perhaps the second `WHEN` should be first?

Comment: Why don't you select `FieldX` in the cte and update the cte directly? You currently have a giant cross join on all matching `staff_id`

Comment: @larnu, indeed the first WHEN statement was a mistake. I updated it accordingly. charlieface not exactly sure what u mean

Comment: @Charlieface is saying to include `FieldX` in the `CTE` and then just run the `UPDATE` against the CTE instead, as both columns you need are in it; then you don't need the `JOIN` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the next query:

```
WITH cte_previous_rows AS (
    SELECT Date, Staff_Id, LAG(FieldX) OVER (partition by Staff_Id ORDER by [date]) as Prev_Row
FROM Sales 
) UPDATE Sales
SET FieldX = (CASE 
    WHEN Staff_id_sales < 1500 AND ClosedSale = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN Staff_id_sales = 1500 and ClosedSale = 0 THEN 5
    WHEN Staff_id_sales > 3000 and (c.Prev_Row = 1 OR c.Prev_Row = 0) THEN 2
    WHEN Staff_id_sales > 3000 and (c.Prev_Row = 2 or c.Prev_Row = 3) THEN 3 
    ELSE FieldX
END) 
FROM Sales
JOIN cte_previous_rows as c ON Sales.staff_id = c.staff_id AND Sales.Date = c.Date;
```

result:

```
+============+==========+================+============+========+
| Date       | Staff_Id | Staff_id_sales | ClosedSale | FieldX |
+============+==========+================+============+========+
| 2000-01-01 | 1        | 500            | 0          | 0      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-01-01 | 2        | 200            | 0          | 0      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-02-26 | 3        | 500            | 0          | 0      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-01-25 | 4        | 1500           | 0          | 5      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-03-25 | 4        | 1500           | 0          | 5      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-03-25 | 5        | 2500           | 0          | 1      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-04-25 | 5        | 3000           | 0          | 1      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-05-25 | 5        | 3500           | 0          | 2      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-05-26 | 5        | 4000           | 0          | 3      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-05-27 | 5        | 5000           | 0          | 3      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
| 2001-05-28 | 5        | 7500           | 0          | 3      |
+------------+----------+----------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: I get the same result as you, but when i run the query, it only updates the next row. I need to update all rows in one go. I suspect your query updates all rows in one go? I used the same query as you provided.

Comment: Marking slava's answer as correct, since it does what it is supposed to. Will instead post a new question with the issue of only one row getting updated per execution.