# SQL UPDATE statement does not update all rows in one execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have a table in MS SQL Server where the EXPECTED result should look like this:
[image: Table]

Prior to expected result/query execution, all FieldX values are NULL. When I run my query, FieldX is only updated from row 2 to 8.

I need to UPDATE FieldX using a set of rules, which I define as such:

```
WITH cte_previous_rows AS (
    SELECT Date, Staff_Id, LAG(FieldX) OVER (partition by Staff_Id ORDER by [date]) as Prev_Row
FROM Sales 
) UPDATE Sales
SET FieldX = (CASE 
    WHEN Staff_id_sales < 1500 AND ClosedSale = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN Staff_id_sales = 1500 and ClosedSale = 0 THEN 5
    WHEN Staff_id_sales <= 3000 and Staff_id_sales > 1500 and ClosedSale = 0 THEN 1
    WHEN Staff_id_sales > 3000 and (c.Prev_Row = 1 OR c.Prev_Row = 0) THEN 2
    WHEN Staff_id_sales > 3000 and (c.Prev_Row = 2 or c.Prev_Row = 3) THEN 3 
    ELSE FieldX
END) 
FROM Sales
JOIN cte_previous_rows as c ON Sales.staff_id = c.staff_id AND Sales.Date = c.Date;
```

This query works just fine. But the problem lies in the last two WHEN statements. The reason for this, is of course that c.Prev_Row (previous row) is used in the rule set for these two last WHEN statements..

How can I edit my query so that the above rule set is applied on to all 50k rows in a SINGLE execution? Perhaps a new method is required..

Comment: Why are you still self joining to Sales to Sales? Like we mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596838/sql-update-and-case-statement-does-not-work#comment115978309_65596838), expose `FieldX` in the CTE and then `UPDATE` the CTE.

Comment: Don't quite understand your problem here. Post more sample data with the expected result to illustrate the issue

Comment: @Larnu yes, this works for optimizing the query. Won't fix the issue at hand tho.

Comment: If only 1 row is being updated, then there is only 1 row being returned from the `FROM`. Without consumable sample data, this is impossible for us to reproduce.

Comment: Updated the description. Should be more easy to understand the issue now :). It was incorrect to say that only one row is being updated.. it's just the WHEN statements, which utilize the previous fieldX value causing trouble.

Example: Before the query is executed, row 8's fieldX value is NULL. Therefore, row 9's fieldX value cannot be updated to = 2. However, running the query one more time, row 8's fieldX value will be = 1 before the SECOND query is run. Therefore, row 9's FieldX value will be updated to 2 this time at the SECOND query execution.

Comment: So what's the problem @jack_st82 ? That's expected, as each time you run the query, the value of the "last" row is changing, and thus so does the logic later.

Comment: @Larnu. Yes. This is expected - indeed. The question at hand in my post is: "How can I edit my query so that the above rule set is applied on to all 50k rows in a SINGLE execution? Perhaps a new method is required". I am aware of the limitations of my method in regards to what I want my output to be. That's why I write in my post "perhaps a new method is required". This hints that I cannot see a different method myself, hence why I ask this exact question in my post.

Comment: If the cte, `cte_previous_rows` returns 50,000 rows, then an `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` will effect all of them, @jack_st82 .

Comment: Since `FieldX` starts as NULL there is no reason to use `Lag` to get the value. You should flip the CTE to a recursive CTE that it calculates `FieldX` values going forward and passing each new value to the next recursion. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and consumable data makes it easier for us to help you, images of data not so much.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE that works from the earliest row for each `Staff_Id` forward may be the ticket:

[image]

Note: This query was not run on an image of the data, so it might have some errors.